# @font-face not working for IE, but is working for chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, font-face, webfonts

So trying to add a custom @font-face font to my asp.net project. Got it working in chrome browser...

```
@font-face
{
font-family: "Century Gothic";
src: url('GOTHIC.TTF'),
}

body {
background-color: #fff;
border-top: solid 10px #000;
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Century Gothic", Segoe UI, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

but need help with the others....(this is my attempt)...but not working:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: "Century Gothic";
    src: url('../GOTHIC.eot');
    src: url('../GOTHIC.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../GOTHIC.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../GOTHIC.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../GOTHIC.svg#URWClassicoItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also not sure if I need the .eot, .woff etc extensions. I have only added

```
GOTHIC.TTF
GOTHICB.TTF
GOTHICBI.TTF
GOTHICI.TTF to my prjoect.
```

working from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115302/font-face-not-working-even-after-trying-everything-i-could-think-of?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238737/font-face-with-embedded-font-does-not-work?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659571/adding-a-custom-font-to-vs-2010-fontface
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894

Answer (score 2):

You need the eot, woff etc file extensions - IE678 doesn't support TTF format, only EOT

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the use of a font across domains.

So the URL that starts `“http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115302/font-face-not-working-even-after-trying-everything-i-could-think-of?rq=1”` is treated as being in a different domain than `“http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8115302/font-face-not-working-even-after-trying-everything-i-could-think-of?rq=1”` even if you see that the domain name refer to the same place of the system.

You need to switch to the **relative url** to get rid of the problem

You may also check **[Cross domain workaround for @font-face and Firefox](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/)** which will help you.

Comment: This isn't the case for the issue at hand - which is that IE isn't displaying the fonts, due to a lack of support for TTF font types.